# angular form in a dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, dialog

I've a form in a $mdDialog called in a angularjs controller, like this:

actions-controller.js

```
  function callForm() {
      $mdDialog.show({
          parent: angular.element(document.body),
          templateUrl: 'template.html',
          scope: $scope,
          controller: 'actionsController'
      }); 
  }

 function saveAction(action, isValid) {

            //code

        actionsRepository.saveAction(action)
        .then(function (data) {

            //other code

            //Close form, do nothing
            $scope.closeActionForm();

           //close dialog, not work
           $scope.close;

        },
        function (error) {
            sharedRepository.handleError(error);

        });
    }
}

 $scope.close = function () {
    $mdDialog.hide();
};
```

template.html

```
    <form name="actionForm" ng-submit="saveAction( crm_act_action_temp,actionForm.$valid)" novalidate>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="end center">
        <md-button type="submit" class="md-primary">save</md-button>

        <md-button type="button" class="md-primary" ng-click="close()">cancel</md-button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My problem is tha the dialog with the form works (open and use the scope) but doesn't close when it ends. Neither is close if I push cancel button, he say me that the colse function is undefined.

Apparently, the $mdDialog remain open and I can´t do nothing more.

Please help.

P.D. I hope explained clearly. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.close` is a function. Call it like this: `$scope.close();`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed

```
$mdDialog.hide();
```

instead of:

```
 $scope.close;
```

?

Comment: Yes, I tried $mdDialog.hide();, but is undefied in this moment. Thanks.

Comment: I use $mdDialog.hide(); before $scope.closeActionForm();, and the modal windows was close but, any button work.

Comment: Can you put your code on plunker please so it is easier to test and find the main reason. It should see $mdDialog in successful response block if it sees $scope.